# Do requests in a batch run In parallel?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As long as I do not use the [dependsOn property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#sequencing-requests-with-the-dependson-property), do the requests in a batch request run in parallel?

I have heard that they may not, and for performance reasons, it may be better to send individual requests in parallel from my code, so I'm wondering if that's truly the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what requests are in the batch and with entities they are touching. But in general yes, requests are run in parallel if you don't add a depends on property. Implementation details may vary though. It is possible that large batches are sliced into subsets of requests and one subset is executed at a time (with all requests in the subset being executed in parallel).

No matter what you'll save HTTP connections handshakes, HTTP request headers and more when using a batch vs lots of requests.

Comment: Thanks! Each request in our batch is just a get for a drive item, GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}, so it seems like the sort of thing that could run in parallel.